# How to create an array from flattened data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a lot of information online to go from flattened data to arrays or structs, but I need to do the opposite and I am having a hard time archiving it. I am using Google BigQuery.

I have something like:

```
| Id | Value1 | Value2 |
|  1 |    1   |    2   |
|  1 |    3   |    4   |
|  2 |    5   |    6   |
|  2 |    7   |    8   |
```

I would like to get for the example above:

```
1, [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
2, [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

If I try to put an array in the select with a group by it is not a valid statement

For example:

```
SELECT Id, [ STRUCT(Value1, Value2) ] as Value
FROM `table.dataset`
GROUP BY Id
```

Which returns:

```
1, (1, 2)
1, (3, 4)
2, (5, 6)
2, (7, 8)
```

Which is not what I am looking for. The structure I got is: `Id, Value.Value1, Value.Value2` and I want `Id, [ Value(V1, V2), Value(V1, V2), ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `SELECT Id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Value1, Value2)) ... GROUP BY Id`

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select id, array_agg((select as struct t.* except(id))) as `value`
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by id
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]